# Left shift byte in C on Microchip 16F876A

Tags: microchip

I'm facing with this problem: working with C for Microchip PIC16F876 microcontroller (HI-TECH PICC compiler), I need to save a number in EEPROM and read it when I switch my device ON. Number dimension requires three bytes (number is 126000 in decimal, corresponding to 0x01EC30), thus I thought to split it in 0x01, 0xEC, 0x30 and save them in three EEPROM locations.
At startup I read the three bytes and join them to obtain my whole variable:

```
unsigned long TotVariable = byte2 << 16 | byte1 << 8 | byte0;
```

check in a watch windows, I found  byte2 left shifted didn't appeared in position I'd like, but the variable dimension seems to be 16 byte only (value of byte2 I found summed to least significant, thus when I read I found 0xFFFFEC31 instead of 0x0001EC30).
How can I solve this issue?
Problem is my variable dimension? Or left shift operation? Compiler can't manage this variable?
Does exist another way to split and join three bytes?

Comment: I'd each one of those shifted expression in parenthesis to begin with.

Comment: Also, `byte2 << 16` by itself should evaluate to zero if `bytes2` is an 8-bit variable.

Comment: And the same goes for `byte1 << 8`.

Comment: TLDR, use `((unsigned long)byte2 << 16) | ((unsigned long)byte1) << 8 | byte0`.